# Downloading Large Files Using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 5 application with Entity Framework behind it. I am implementing an export functionality to export user's data. The user can select records and click export, and expect a file to get downloaded in the form of HTML.

Now I have got the process working for small number of records but it won't work as the file grows. I believe there has to be a way for the app to stream the result rather than constructing it the way I am. I explain:

In the view I do something like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExportRecords", "UserData", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.Hidden("selectedRecordIds", "1;2;3;4")
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" />
}
```

In the controller, I get the records from DB+Azure, and generate HTML and kick off the download:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExportRecords(string selectedRecordIds)
{
    var selectedRecordsIdList = selectedRecordIds.Split(";".ToCharArray()).ToList();

    var records = await GetRecords(selectedRecordsIdList);

    var recordsAsHtml = await Helper.GenerateHtml(records);

    return File(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(recordsAsHtml),System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "ExportedFile.html");}
```

Now the cut-down version of GenerateHtml method looks like:

```
public static async Task<string> GenerateHtml(List<Records> records)
{
    var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    using (var writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
    {
        foreach (var record in records)
        {
           writer.Indent++; 
           writer.Write("<tr>");
           writer.WriteLine();
            ......
        }
    }

    // This could cause "Out of Memory Exception"
    var htmlContent = stringWriter.ToString();

    return htmlContent;
}
```

So using the above, I put some for loop around the foreach to simulate a scenario where there are thousands of records, and pretty soon I was getting Out of Memory Exception.

So what is the best way to export large amount of data?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: 1, I didn't see why do you need to download html by that way. why not `return PartialView(records)` directly?; 2, you need to add `[HTTPPOST]` attribute on action. 3, `GenerateHtml` use `HtmlTextWriter`, it's my first time to see it's used in web server, just delete this function, and do same work in a `PartialView`

Comment: One way to minimize the memory footprint is to return a "minimized" html file. I only say minimized as the actual html line formatting (tabs, indentations, new lines) aren't required for html to render (it's only there for human readability). Removing these will reduce the overall footprint, however, in the end this may only reduce the frequency of the issue. You might end up needing to write the results to a temp file on the web server, then simply return that temp file back in the response. Just be sure the temp file is unique to be sure 2 requests don't override one another.

Comment: @Dongdong thanks for the reply. To answer your questions: 1) Intention is for the file to be downloaded not rendered. I believe return PartialView will render the HTML. 2) I have [HTTPPOST] in the code. I guess I didn't show it here since it is kind of irrelevant to the question. 3) GenerateHtml is more than a few lines of code and where it is implemented is also irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @bman7716 thanks for the reply. Yes I agree, minimized will help but not for long. In terms of using temp file, might work if somehow I can pipe the GenerateHtml to write to a FileStream. Another approach for future could be, that the webapp could put a job request into a queue (e.g DB table) and another API could pick it up and generate the stream of strings into an Azure blob stream. Then once its done, it can email the link to the user. But I still believe there has to be an easier way to generate stream of strings into the user's download stream, so that not much CPU/memory gets used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after hours of trial, I think I have a reasonable solution. Basically, the problem I wanted to solve was to write steady stream of characters to the stream that is getting downloaded to the users computer/browser as a file. Now what I managed to do is to write my string in chunks at the time to a `MemoryStream`, then write that `MemoryStream` to `Response` and then flush the `MemoryStream`. I simulated at one stage with over 2Gig of file and the RAM didn't increase and stayed steady until the end. The code below shows what I mean:

```
    public ActionResult Download()
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.BufferOutput = false;
        Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=records.html");

        var subString = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < 500000000; i++)
        {
            subString += "<sometag></sometag>";

            if (subString.Length > 100)
            {
                var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(subString);
                var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

                Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());

                stream.Flush();
                stream.Close();
                stream.Dispose();

                subString = string.Empty;
            }
        }

        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
        Response.End();

        return null;
    }
```

This might help someone else.